# Unable to parse particular JSON data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

This is a question I truly feel stupid for asking. But I have searched the web and haven't found a specific example with my problem. Luckily, the question is simple. I have the following JSON data being read in by AngularJS as follows:

```
return $http.post('getData.htm').then(function(response) {
    console.log("response.data: " + response.data);
    var roles = angular.fromJson(response.data).model.results;

    return roles;
  });
```

The console in this scenario outputs the following:

```
 response.data: {"model":{"results":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"],"totalCount":11}}
```

I expect `roles` to contain an array with those numbers, however when I print out the value of `roles` it simply says `[object Object]`.

How do I access the numbers contained in the `results` array?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to print as: `JSON.stringify(response.data)`?

Comment: `response.data` is all you need. In adding the `angular.fromJson` call, you're effectively creating another object, deserialized from the JSON response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A javascript Array is also an Object so maybe when you did `var roles = angular.fromJson(response.data).model.results;` you got the array you wanted. Try roles[1]

Comment: This was indeed the answer. I swear I tried this a billion times. That's programming, I guess :). thank you for the help!

Comment: Thanks for that answer!! I searched the web and found everyone using JSON.parse but unfortunately that didn't worked. Your answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to "load from JSON" a JSON object.

`response.data` is already transformed in JSON format by angular.. Just use it like that :

```
console.log(response.data.model);
console.log(response.data.model.results);
console.log(response.data.model.results[1]);
```

Comment: When I try this, the following occurs: The first line outputs `undefined` and the second causes `TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined`

Comment: if console.log(response.data) returns you an object with a 'model' key, it should definitely work...

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/duruy/1/edit

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $http){

activate();
  $scope.roles = [];

function activate ()
  {

    return $http.get('http://jsbin.com/yewefo/1').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data.model);
   angular.copy(response.data.model.results, $scope.roles);


  });

  }

});
```